# Python matplotlib. Trying to plot binary signal, getting interpolation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey probably a simple question, but cant find the answer to this. I am monitoring a series of bits with a timestamp. I can plot the state of them just fine, but in the plots there are a skewed line between 0->1 and 1->0, where there should just be a straight line at the time they switch. How to avoid this skewed line? It makes it look like i have values in between when i dont.

[image]

EDIT: As pointed out below, using step instead of plot solves the problem. Thanks:)

Comment: `matplotlib` simply connects the data points with a line by default. The other option would be to simply plot the points as "markers". Change your script to plt.plot(..., linestyle="none", marker="o"), this will give you circular markers at the data positions. For other markers, have a look here: http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html

Comment: May you provide your code?

Comment: In a line-plot, two points will be connected with a line, and the line will be tilted (vertically) if the two points do not have the same x-dimension. That's just how it is. If you want to avoid that, you can (a) do a scatter plot with points only or (b) zoom out a lot to trick your eye or (c) overlay lines or do a custom fit function [(Heaviside?)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside-Funktion).

Comment: @mapt  Accept the answer. Don't edit the question saying the answer works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `plt.step` function instead of plot,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def heaviside(x):
    return .5*(np.sign(x)+1.)

x = np.linspace(0,100,10)
y = heaviside(np.random.random(10)-.5)

plt.step(x,y)
plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
plt.show()
```

which gives,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [stemplot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stem_plot.html):

```
plt.stem(x, y)
```

or a [step plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html)

```
plt.step(x, y)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't even know about `plt.step`.